I am having trouble with hierarchy in objects. Particularly, an array in an object which is used in another object
This is a c# program.
I have a number of Microcontrollers on a board, each of which can have different configurations.
To describe this I make a Config class which defines a configuration (name, number etc)
Among the Configuration fields is an array of 4 bytes.
Now I make a couple of configurations, then set their values.
It works.
Now I try creating the configurations and setting values at the same time. It doesn't work. The array ends up with the same values in both configurations, even though they are separate objects. No warnings or errors.
Here's the code. The comments tell you what goes wrong.
public class Config
{
    public byte ConfigNum { get; set; }
    public byte[] ConfigData { get; set; } = new byte[4];
}
static void Main()
{
    Config c0 = new Config();
    Config c1 = new Config();

    c0.ConfigNum = 11;
    c0.ConfigData[3] = 13;

    c1.ConfigNum = 22;
    c1.ConfigData[3] = 23;

    // Check whats in there
    Console.WriteLine(c0.ConfigNum); // Expect 11
    Console.WriteLine(c0.ConfigData[3]); // Expect 13
    Console.WriteLine(c1.ConfigNum); // Expect 22
    Console.WriteLine(c1.ConfigData[3]); // Expect 23

    // Now try to make configurations on the fly
    byte[] RConfigData1 = { 11, 12, 13, 14 }; // Make a temporary array

    Config c3 = new Config() // Make and add a configuration with the values in the temporary array
    {
        ConfigNum = 55,
        ConfigData = RConfigData1
    };

    RConfigData1[3] = 24; // change a value in the temporary array

    Config c4 = new Config() // Make and add a configuration with the values in the temporary array
    {
        ConfigNum = 66,
        ConfigData = RConfigData1
    };

    // Check whats in there
    Console.WriteLine(c3.ConfigNum); // Expect 55
    Console.WriteLine(c3.ConfigData[3]); // Expect 14 BUT GET 24
    Console.WriteLine(c4.ConfigNum); // Expect 66
    Console.WriteLine(c4.ConfigData[3]); // Expect 24
}


"The array ends up with the same values in both configurations, even though they are separate objects." - there's only one array though. The values of c3.ConfigData and c4.ConfigData both refer to the same object.  The value of ConfigData is a reference. If you're not familiar yet with how reference types work in C#, that's the next thing to research, I'd say.

"even though they are separate objects." - tell us more about what "they" refers to here. If you're referring to c3/c4 then you're right, they are indeed separate objects.. But if it refers to the arrays, then they aren't actually separate objects. You have two separate config objects sharing the same array object (hence what you see). It's always more interesting to me, when beginners come with questions like this, to understand how they have mentally modelled the c# program, than it is to fix the program and hope they can work out how to update their mental model from the fixed version

Thank you all, yes, it was the Reference types that caught me out. The Objects and Hierarchy were red herrings. BTW my mental picture was of two objects, each with its own array attached. I have changed that to two objects, each with a dangling line, which may attach to the same array, or different arrays. (Or parts of different arrays? I'll try it)

This is because your ConfigData is byte[], Array in C# is reference type instead of value type.
From Microsoft documentation of Array:

Array types are reference types derived from the abstract base type Array. All arrays implement IList and IEnumerable. You can use the foreach statement to iterate through an array. Single-dimensional arrays also implement IList and IEnumerable.

Reference type holds the a reference to the memory address holding the byte array. Therefore when your line setting RConfigData[3]modified the state ofc3`:
RConfigData1[3] = 24;

Then you assigned the same reference to c4, that means whatever you change in RConfigData1 will reflect on both c3 and c4.
If you want to copy the values of RConfigData1 and then use it in c4 you can do this:
var RConfigData2 = new byte[4];
Array.Copy(RConfigData1, RConfigData2, RConfigData1.Length);
RConfigData2[3] = 24; // change a value in the temporary array

Config c4 = new Config() // Make and add a configuration with the values in the temporary array
{
    ConfigNum = 66,
    ConfigData = RConfigData2
};

Then the output will become:
11
13
22
23
55
14
66
24

You can refer to this post and documentation from Microsoft as well:

What is the difference between a reference type and value type in c#?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types


Thank you, yes I see how that breaks the link and makes a nice new array.
